# Iterate List<Map<String, Object>> and add the values of object to a list using Java

Tags: java

Im having a List> as

```
[{TXNO=428, STATUS=NEW}, {TXNO=434, STATUS=NEW}, {TXNO=442, STATUS=NEW}]
```

I'm iterating the object as

```
for (Map<String, Object> map : details) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                Object value = entry.getValue();
                logger.info(key+"="+value);
            }
        }
```

It prints as

```
TXNO=428
STATUS=NEW
TXNO=434
STATUS=NEW
TXNO=442
STATUS=NEW
```

How can I add TXNO values in a list? My List object finally should be [428,434, 442]

Comment: Check if the key equals "TXNO" and if true add the value to your list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<String> TXNOList = new LinkedList<String>();

for (Map<String, Object> map : details) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                Object value = entry.getValue();
                logger.info(key+"="+value);
                if(key.equals("TXNO")) {
                    TXNO.add(value);
                }
            }
        }
```

If you need a Integer list just change the TXNOList definition to Integer and cast value to Integer: `Integer.valueOf(value)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use java 8, then here's an elegant solution:

```
List<Object> txno = mapList.stream()
            .map(map -> map.get("TXNO")) // get value by key
            .filter(Objects::nonNull) // check if not null
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect to list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do  this way :-

```
List<Object> TXList=new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (Map<String, Object> map : details) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            if(key.equals("TXNO"))
            TXList.add(value);
        }
    }
```